# VBA creation of a Matrix and double loop

Tags: vba, excel, loops, matrix

I have a lot of Excel files in one folder and for each one I have (H:H) which contains a certain hour from 00:00 to 23:59 (appears within H at the format 0000 or 2359 etc ..) .
Then, at a certain hour we associate a certain number of operation (contains by column A) in the same sheet, but the time is not "homogeneous" , for example we can have 0012 at H4 on sheet 1 and 0014 in H4 on sheet number 2, meaning that time is not divided the same way according each sheet.

```
Sheet 1     Sheet 2     
0010        ;0004   
0017        ;0014    
0018        ;0023    
0025,       ;0045    
0025        ;0057    
0031    
0035    
0055
```

I am trying to create a matrix with VBA on another sheet which would sum the number of operation only for a time-slot, I wish basically 00:15 to 00:59 , 01:00 to 01:59 ... and fill the matrix with the number of operation present in column A which correspond at the number of operation for the period of time (the hour) for each excel sheet of my folder.

The matrix I am trying to make would have the following form:

```
      0000-0059 (H1)     0100-0159 (H2)    0200-0259 (H3)    0300-0359 (H4)...... 2300:2359(H24)
1

2

3

4

.

.


till, "number of files in my folder"
```

I had the idea to do something like it, but I realized the problem is not that simple ...

```
Sub Dailytraffic()
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
 Dim wB As Workbook
Dim SumResult As Double

Dim H1, H2, H3, H4, H5, H6, H7, H8, H9, H10, H11, H12, H13, H14, H15, H16, H17, H18, H19, H20, H21, H22, H23, H24 As Double

Dim OutPutRange As Range

Set FileSystemObj = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")

    Set FolderObj = FileSystemObj.GetFolder("C:\...\")

 Set OutPutRange = Workbooks("Libro1").Sheets("Hoja1").Range("D4")

 Set H1RAN = Workbooks("Libro1").Sheets("Hoja1").Range("B1")
 Set H2RAN = Workbooks("Libro1").Sheets("Hoja1").Range("C1")
 Set H3RAN = Workbooks("Libro1").Sheets("Hoja1").Range("D1")
 .
 .
 .
 Set H24RAN = Workbooks("Libro1").Sheets("Hoja1").Range("AA1")

  Set wB = Workbooks.Open(fileobj.Path)
 For Each fileobj In FolderObj.Files

Dim i As Long
 For i = 1 To 300
 If (0 <= Left(wB.Sheets("Schedule Daily Bank Structure R").Cells(8, 4 + i).Value, 2) < 1) Then

 H1 = WorksheetFunction.Sum(wB.Sheets("Schedule Daily Bank Structure R").Cells(1, i))

H1RAN.Value = H1

      Set H1RAN = H1RAN.Offset(1, 0)

 For j = 1 To 300
 If (1 <= Left(wB.Sheets("Schedule Daily Bank Structure R").Cells(8, 4 + j).Value, 2) < 2) Then

 H2 = WorksheetFunction.Sum(wB.Sheets("Schedule Daily Bank Structure R").Cells(1, i))

H2RAN.Value = H2

      Set H2RAN = H2RAN.Offset(1, 0)

End If
 Next i
  Next j
  wB.Save
   wB.Close


  Next fileobj

End Sub
```

My Idea would be to repeat 24-2 times more, but it does not seem to work.  I have trouble to mix the loop which manages to sum for each different period of time and the Loop which go through the different files ... I am blocked here.

Comment: Does this run now?  There are a few quick issues I noticed when indenting the code - you do `Next i` before `Next j`. Also you're missing an `End If` in between (as you have it) `Next J // Next i`.

Comment: Yes true,  No it does not work, It seems that my method has some problems ...